# Find text ending with words defined in array

Tags: vba, excel

For instance, I want to see whether each cell from B10 till the end of the B colomn is ending with "@yahoo.com", "@gmail.com", "@rediffmail.com". If not then, it should color that particular cell.

Here is what I tried:

[image]

Here are the cons:

1. Its searching entire sheet, instead a column.
2. Its coloring entire row, instead that particular cell
3. I want to highlight the cell, which do not end with above domains.

Comment: What have you already got that didn't work?  Also, conditional formatting might be a useful alternative.

Comment: Thanks Carl. I have edited the question and uploaded the code which I have used till now. I actually, want all the cells in that particular column to be highlighted in which data do not end with any of the domains mentioned.

Comment: @CarlColijn: I have provided the code above. Can you please help me in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:
1) variant using `array` to store search keys:

```
Sub test()
    Dim cl As Range, Data As Range
    Dim searchTerms, k, trigger%
    searchTerms = Array("yahoo.com", "gmail.com", "rediff.co")
    Set Data = Range("B10:B" & [B:B].Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row)
    For Each cl In Data
        trigger = 0
        For Each k In searchTerms
            If LCase(cl.Value2) Like "*" & LCase(k) Then
                trigger = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next k
        If trigger = 0 Then
            cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
        Else
            cl.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

2) variant using the range with searching keys:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim cl As Range, Data As Range
    Dim k As Range, searchTerms As Range, trigger%
    Dim S1 As Worksheet, S2 As Worksheet

    Set S1 = Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to sheetname with data for comparing
    Set S2 = Sheets("Sheet2") ' chanfe to sheetname with search keys

    Set Data = S1.Range("B10:B" & S1.[B:B].Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row)
    Set searchTerms = S2.[A1:A3] '"yahoo.com", "gmail.com", "rediff.co"
    For Each cl In Data
        trigger = 0
        For Each k In searchTerms
            If LCase(cl.Value2) Like "*" & LCase(k.Value2) Then
                trigger = 1: Exit For
            End If
        Next k
        If trigger = 0 Then
            cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
        Else
            cl.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

3) variant using `scripting.dictionary` and range with search terms:

```
Sub test3()
    Dim cl As Range, Data As Range, Cnt As Long
    Dim S1 As Worksheet, S2 As Worksheet
    Dim searchTerms As Object, WrdArray() As String
    Set searchTerms = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    searchTerms.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    Set S1 = Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to sheetname with data for comparing
    Set S2 = Sheets("Sheet2") ' chanfe to sheetname with search keys

    For Each cl In S2.[A1:A4] '"yahoo.com", "gmail.com", "rediff.co", "internal.yahoo.com"
        If Not searchTerms.exists(cl.Value2) Then
            searchTerms.Add cl.Value2, Nothing
        End If
    Next cl

    Set Data = S1.Range("B10:B" & S1.[B:B].Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row)
    Cnt = 0
    For Each cl In Data
        WrdArray() = Split(cl.Value2, "@")
        If Not searchTerms.exists(Split(cl.Value2, "@")(UBound(WrdArray()))) Then
            cl.Interior.Color  = vbYellow: Cnt = Cnt + 1
        Else
            cl.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End If
    Next cl
    If Cnt > 0 Then 
        Msgbox "Total count of incorrect entries is [" & Cnt & _ 
        "] all discrepancies have been highlighted with Yellow!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to hi-light cells which doesnt end with those array of words.

Comment: This code does exactly what you asking for, if cell doesn't end with one of the words then it will be highlighted

Comment: Vasily, I want to declare the yahoo.com, gmail.com in a array and then to compare it...as I have lot of domains...BTW thanks for the code...:)

Comment: See updated variant. Also, as an additional option, you can use the range of cells where you can store your list of search keys, for example in hidden sheet, it will be more manageable option than updating of the code, just unhide the sheet and insert or delete required serching value. if you need such variant, let me know

Comment: @Vasily...Yeah, I'm looking for the hidden variant. Moreover, When I correct the entry with correct domain and re-run the script, it is not removing the color of that particular color which was incorrect earlier. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Perfect @Vasily...I have one last question...I have entries abc@yahoo.com, def@internl.yahoo.com.
The search terms has, yahoo.com and internal.yahoo.com.
When I run the script, it is not highlighting the internl.yahoo.com, as it is searching for only yahoo.com and says its correct. 
But, actually it should hi-light it, because of mispell of correct domain.
Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: You can add `@` to the search term, so instead of search terms `yahoo.com` and `internal.yahoo.com` use `@yahoo.com` `@internal.yahoo.com`. And if you have all entries like `something@somedomain.com` then there are another options to achieve required result with using more faster solutions, for example using `split()` function and `find()` method, or again using `split()` and `scripting.dictionary` e.g. `dic.exists(split(cl.Value2, "@")(1))`. So, if you need such variants, let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking something of that kind @Vasily...few of the usernames have @ in the username ex: rob@23@gmail.com...the formula should consider last appearance of '@'...so that it would be helpful..:)

Comment: @Vasily..it is not working if the entry has more than one '@'. Can we use Right function to consider the first appearance of '@' and compare the rest of the word with the search terms??

Comment: @Vasily...I want macro to highlight all the cells with incorrect domain and it is doing perfect. When try to add a MsgBox, it is prompting as soon as it finds the first error. 
however, I want the prompt only after it finds all the incorrect cells and a single prompt like "All incorrect entries are found in Yellow colored Cells".
Could you help me in that??

Comment: @Prashanth usually, for such purposes I use a counter, so you can declare variable as long, and increase itself in loop each time when condition is true, and before the end of sub you need to verify this variable, an if it's grater than zero then 'do something'. The 3rd posted variant been updated (not tested because of was typed via phone, but it should works fine)